# Define the same option twice in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

In **Tornado** I want to use base `settings.py` file, that import `prod_settings.py` and `local_settings.py`.

So, the options in that modules can repeat each other. For example, `DEBUG=False` in **prod_settings** and `DEBUG=True` in **local_settings**.

But I have an error

```
tornado.options.Error: Option 'DEBUG' already defined.
```

How I understand, I can't define twice the same option.

Why? How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define an option more than once. You could set a variable `DEFAULT_DEBUG` in `prod_settings.py` and `local_settings.py` and then use that as the default when you call `define('DEBUG', default=DEFAULT_DEBUG)` in `settings.py`.

But this question suggests that you're going about things in the wrong way. In `tornado.options`, the intended pattern is to define the options once in your code, and then the values come from *outside* the code, via the command line (or config file, but command line is more idiomatic). So you wouldn't have conditional imports of `local_settings.py` or `prod_settings.py`, but instead you'd have `run-local.sh` and `run-prod.sh` to pass in the appropriate flags.